# Pressing and holding "e" over end of word that ends in a ":"

Tags: keyboard, macos

[image]

What steps will reproduce the problem?
0. Using RubyMine
1. Use IdeaVim
2. Hold down "e" to auto-repeat end of word
3. Hit a : at end of word
4. See picture! I can pick lots of strange "e" characters.

What is the expected result?
This should not happen. How to turn this off?

Cross reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16003

However, I think this is a Mac issue, as this just happened after the recent upgrade.

Comment: This might fix the issue:
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false

However, this was not necessary before. Probably a way to set this in the app!

Comment: I don't think so - that's a system-level popup (note how it doesn't follow the RubyMine theme). The `defaults` command you gave should indeed kill it off.

Comment: I wonder if this as something to do with this weeks Yosemite big update?

Comment: This is a Mac feature, yes. If you want the software you are using to disable that popup, you would need to address this with the developer of the software (as you appear to have done). There is nothing we can do to resolve it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for specific non-Apple software.

Comment: It's not obvious this is a problem with the given application, so this is not off-topic. Also, this changed with the last Yosemite update that required reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the author of the software addressing this, the following command turns off the press and hold, bring up the e's:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```